# Incorporate mqtt into appcelerator / titanium

Tags: module, appcelerator, mqtt, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop

Does anybody have successful experience incorporating an `mqtt library` into Appcelerator / Titanium?

1. What library have you used
2. How do you incorporate that library (i.e. npm module, hyperloop, cocoapods,
   straight source code, etc)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a any usable implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

The only existing module I could find is http://gitt.io/component/it.uhopper.mqtt but last updated in 2014. So you'll have to find an (iOS?) library and then either [wrap it as module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile) or use [Hyperloop](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/blob/master/Podfile) but be aware that HL is still in beta.